# Vaadin 7 custom TextField

Tags: java, html, css, user-interface, vaadin

I am using `Vaadin 7 rc2`. Also know, that I am fairly new to `Vaadin` at all.

I would like to create a custom `TextField` which has the required start at the right of the `input`, and which highlights the `input` istead of showing the exclamation mark when the validation fails:

[image]

(I have a select box on the screenshot, but you get the idea ....)

How could I achieve this? The [Vaadin 7 wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin+7) has a custom widget tutorial but as far as I have seen that is not what I want.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is to create my own widget, which I can style and display as I want.

Comment: You are correct and this can be a starting point if you have not already read https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.eclipse.html#gwt.eclipse.widget